# Como fazer um LOOP ser executado de acordo com o retorno de um Promise (promessa)?

Tags: javascript, promises

Como consigo fazer meu loop esperar pelo retorno de uma promise?

Digamos que tenho o seguinte código:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
   // algumalógica
   fazAlgumaCoisa(array[i]);
}

var fazAlgumaCoisa = function(obj) {
   $http.get(url).then(function success(response) {

   }, function error(response) {

   });
}
```

Minha dúvida é: como faço pro meu for aguardar o retorno dessa chamada `http`?

Comment: Podes explicar em que contexto queres usar essa funcionalidade? Sem saber o que queres fazer vamos estar a adivinhar uma solução que pode não ser útil.

Comment: Você poderia especificar que esta usando um script de http: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Creating_a_Promise_2

Comment: tenho um videoplayer onde a configuração do que irá tocar é descrita em diversos arquivos. Eu preciso, antes de tocar, garantir que todos os arquivos tenham sido lido em memória. Para pegar o arquivo, eu tenho que acessar a um WS que me retorna isso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Coloco uma resposta com uma ideia que ainda ninguém referiu, e que penso ser a melhor opção. Usando [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Quando descreves que precisas *"antes de tocar, garantir que todos os arquivos tenham sido lido em memória."* isso é exatamente o que o `Promise.all` faz.

Passando uma array de *Promises* a essa *Promise.all* ela espera que **todas** estejam resolvidas e retorna uma `Promise` que recebe como argumento do método de sucesso uma array com os valores das Promises passadas. Se passares valores estáticos (Strings, Objetos, ou outras variáveis que não sejam assíncronas) ele usa na mesma, chamando o `Promise.resolve` imediatamente. Por isso a `Promise.all` aceita uma array mista, com Promises ou não.

Um exemplo simples seria assim: https://jsfiddle.net/4s5L4s7c/, o que precisas no teu caso seria algo assim:

```
var urls = ['/pasta/a', '/pasta/b' /* etc... */ ];

function get(url, i) {
    return $http.get(url); <-- isto será o que queres
}

Promise.all(urls.map(get)).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res); // aqui "res" é uma array com a resposta de cada "$http.get", na mesma ordem da array "urls".
}, function() {
    console.log('Algo falhou!');
});
```

Comment: Eu acho essa a melhor solução, ela é simples, usa recursos da própria linguagem e tem algo que não foi citado que ela tem vantagem comparada as outras respostas: aqui temos diversas requisições em paralelo, usando a verdadeira vantagem do assincronismo do JS a seu favor. As outras soluções (que são ótimas também) efetuam uma requisição por vez.

Comment: Sergio, dentro desse Promise.all(), onde tu esta passando uma urls.map(get), eu poderia passar promises criadas na mão?

Comment: @PauloGustavo exato. O método .all aceita uma array, de Promises ou de valores/objetos.

Comment: Não conhecia isso, achei bem interessante e funcional!!

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar o [conceito de filas (*queues*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)).

Prepare uma coleção contendo os itens que deseja processar, e execute processamentos individuais até que a fila se esgote.

Uma das vantagens deste padrão é que ele permite que você inclua novos itens na fila mesmo durante execução do laço principal.

Abaixo, um exemplo de fila serial FIFO (*First In, First Out* - ou entre primeiro, saia primeiro):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
var app = angular.module("exemplo", []); 

app.controller("filaController", function($scope, $http) {

  var that = this;
  
  // Itens iniciais a serem processados
  this.ZipCodesAPesquisar = [77379, 77380, 77381];

  this.processaProximaEntrada = function(){
    //Existem itens na minha fila? Se sim, processe o primeiro.
    if (that.ZipCodesAPesquisar.length > 0){
      that.processaFila(that.ZipCodesAPesquisar[0]);
      return;
    }
  }

  this.processaFila = function (unidade){

    this.removeDaFila = function(unidade){
      //Localiza a posição da unidade na fila
      var indice = that.ZipCodesAPesquisar.indexOf(unidade);

      //Caso encontrado, remova:
      if (indice != -1) {
        that.ZipCodesAPesquisar.splice(indice, 1);
        
        // Verifique se ainda existem itens na fila.
        that.processaProximaEntrada();
      }
    }

    console.log("Processando " + unidade);

    $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + unidade + '&sensor=true')
    .then(function success(response) {
      console.log(response.data.results[0].formatted_address);
      that.removeDaFila(unidade);
    }, function error(response) {
      that.removeDaFila(unidade);
    });    
  };

  //Inicializa processamento da fila
  this.processaProximaEntrada();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="exemplo" ng-controller="filaController">
</div>
```

Comment: Bonito. Esse negócio da fila eu gostei :D

Answer (score 3):

Você pode trabalhar com recursividade. Você usa uma função anônima nomeada para fazer referência a ela mesma e, se estiver dentro das condições, você executa ela novamente. A condição colocada evita a recursividade infinita.

```
var exemplo = function next(i) {


    $http.get(url).then(function success(response) {

        next.loop >=  i && next(++i);

    }, function error(response) {

        next.loop >= i && next(++i);
    });
}

exemplo.loop = 10;

exemplo(0);
```

No caso acima, enquanto a propriedade da função `loop` for maior que `i`, a recursão será aplicada. A função anônima nomeada internamente de `next`, será executada apenas quando o `success` ou `error` for chamada por `$http.get`.

Eu fiz um pequeno exemplo para você entender o funcionamento disso. É uma função que escreve um valor no `HTML`. Ela vai escrever enquanto o valor do `loop` for maior que o de `i`. É o mesmo caso acima, mas aplicado com um  `setTimeout` para você entender a lógica da minha recursão:

```js
var counter = function _fn(i) {

    _fn.loop > i && setTimeout(function () { 
     _fn(++i) 
         document.body.innerHTML = i;
    }, 1000);
}

counter.loop = 10;

counter(0)
```

Comment: Só gostaria de entender o por quê do -1, já que a resposta faz com que o loop seja executado apenas quando termina a requisição anterior. Não entendo mesmo

Comment: Pra mim, a resposta ta ótima. Só estou testando no meu caso pra ver como vai se comportar :)

Comment: Acho a resposta interessante mas em vez de iterar sobre numeros era bom receber uma array com arquivos ou url para esses arquivos e depois mapear tudo para a callback final que executa quando essas promisses tiverem resolvido. Há várias maneiras de fazer isso. Se o @PauloGustavo esclarecer mais a pergunta junto também uma resposta mais logo.

Comment: @Sergio agora entendi. Talvez o problema seja que a resposta foi dada em cima de uma pergunta que não tem muito detalhes.

Answer (score 3):

Similar a [resposta do @WallaceMaxters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137756/14213), mas na pratica com o [script que você esta usando](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Creating_a_Promise_2).

```
function loopPromise(url, start, end, callSuccess, callError){

    $http = new $http(url); // Gera a promise para a url solicitada 

    var func = function(obj){
        $http.get().then(function success(response){
            if(typeof callSuccess == 'function'){
                callSuccess('loaded'+start);  // chama sua função de sucesso, caso tenha sido definida
            }
            if(start++ < end){
                func(); // gera o loop ate start ser = a end
            }
        }, function(response){
            if(typeof callError == 'function'){
                callError(response); // chama sua função de erro, caso tenha sido definida, e não propaga mais o loop
            }
        });
    }
    func();
}

url = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js';
loopPromise(url, 0, 10, function(response){
    console.log(response);
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Então quer dizer que minha resposta não tá errada :D. +1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters ou nos dois estamos :P