# Usando Q promise para receber valores de apis diferentes

Tags: node.js, promises, q.js

Preciso receber os valores de algumas APIS.
Por exemplo: as chamadas a `api1()` e `api2()` retornam `deferred.promise`;

Eu consigo:

```
api1().then( function(res1){
  api2().then( function(res2){
       console.log(res1, res2);
  })
});
```

Como posso melhorar essas chamadas as apis usando Q promises?

tentei usar algo como: `Q.fcall(api1()).then(api2())`...

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137828/129, acho que é isso que queres. No teu caso seria `Q.all([api1(),api2()]).then(function(res){console.log(res[0],res[1]); });`. Testa e diz se funciona com a api do `Q.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que o equivalente a Promise.all no `Q.js` é `Q.all`, com a mesma funcionalidade da API nativa. Assim podes fazer:

```
Q.all([api1(), api2()]).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res[0], res[1]);
});
```

Ele espera que todas as QPromises sejam resolvidas e depois continua passando a `res` no exemplo uma array com os valores correspondentes do `resolve` de cada QPromise inicial.

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado, Sergio!!