# Alternativas de encadeamento de funções assíncronas

Tags: javascript, node.js

Preciso realizar 3 `select`. Um em cada tabela, e o seu resultado preciso utilizar nos `select` restantes.

Na aplicação original, eu faço uma série de manipulações no resultado de cada consulta, o que deixa muito conteúdo, então eu resumo meu problema no seguinte código:

```
selectFields('select campo1 from tabela1 where id == 1', function(value1){
    selectFields('select campo2 from tabela2 where id = 1', function(value2){
        selectFields('select campo3 from tabela3 where id = 1', function(value3){
            console.log(value3);
        });
    });
});
```

O `selectField` é uma função onde eu envio a query e ele retorna o valor do select no banco.

O que eu quero é algo mais otimizado do que utilizar um dentro do outro, e ter de esperar o resultado. Imaginem que eu necessite utilizar mais tabelas, ficaria ainda maior.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesta resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/140634/129, lá e nos links indico 4 maneiras diferentes de fazer isto. É isso que procuras?

Comment: Talvez sim, pelo que entendi, o promise permite uma função ser executada apenas quando a função anterior estiver sido terminada ? @Sergio

Comment: Vou dar uma resposta ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Para resolver este tipo de problema onde os métodos a usar são assíncronos é preciso analizar se o caso em questão precisa de **encadeamento** ou **paralelismo**.

Para além de maneiras nativas para este tipo de problemas há uma [biblioteca muito útil "Async"](https://github.com/caolan/async) que uso frequentemente para estas situações e vou referí-la nos exemplos da resposta.

> ## Encadeamento

Encadeamento é quando as funções precisam do resultado da função anterior. Este é o caso mais complexo e implica funções que esperam uma pela outra e são chamadas sequencialmente.

**A maneira mais óbvia**, que é a que estás a evitar pois gera código em cascata dificil de ler e manter é:

```
fnA(a, function(err, resA){
    fnB(b, function(err, resB){
        fnC(c, function(err, resC){
            fnD(d, function(err, resD){
                // etc...
```

Em alguns casos mais simples, esta pode ser a mais prática.

**Se usares a biblioteca `async`** podes usar o [`compose`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.compose), onde podes encadear N funções. A régra é que cada tem dois argumentos: a variável a trabalhar com os dados, e a callback com `erro` no primeiro argumento e os dados a passar no segundo.

O exemplo da documentação:

```
function add1(n, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback(null, n + 1);
    }, 10);
}

function mul3(n, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback(null, n * 3);
    }, 10);
}

var add1mul3 = async.compose(mul3, add1);
add1mul3(4, function (err, result) {
    // O resultado é 15
});
```

**Se quiseres usar JavaScript nativo** podes fazer assim:
(fiz um exemplo usando a mesma API do Async)

```
function encadear() {
    var cadeia = [].slice.call(arguments);
    return function(dadoInicial, end) {
    var fns = cadeia.slice();
        function exec(err, data) {
            if (err) return end(err);
            var next = fns.pop();
            if (!next) return end(null, data);
            next(data, exec);
        }
        exec(null, dadoInicial);
    }
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c3sgt0gu/1

**Outra maneira de fazer isto é com [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise),** que permitem também encadear funções assíncronas. Um exemplo seria assim, usando o mesmo exemplo que os de cima:

```
function waitFor(fn) {
    return function(val) {
        return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
            fn(val, function(err, data) {
                if (err) rej(err);
                else res(data);
            })
        });
    }
}

Promise.resolve(4)
    .then(waitFor(add1))
    .then(waitFor(mul3))
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result); // 15
    }
);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9mdqqb8e/

> ## Paralelismo

Paralelismo é quando tens várias funções assíncronas que têm de ser completadas antes de passar á proxima fase do código **mas não dependem umas das outras**. Ou seja podem correr independentemente e só queremos esperar pelo final de todas.

Neste conceito é preciso diferênciar casos onde precises de usar o resultado de cada uma dessas funções ou caso elas não tenham resultado a retornar. Será o caso de um `.map()` / mapeamento assíncrono ou um `.forEach` / loop / iterador simples.

**Se usares a biblioteca `async`** podes usar o `async.map` ou `async.each` caso precises dos resultados ou não.

Um exemplo da documentação é assim, onde se pretende saber o estado de N ficheiros, onde todos usam uma dada função `fs.stat`:

```
async.map(['file1','file2','file3'], fs.stat, function(err, results) {
    // a variável "results" tem uma array na mesma ordem que os nomes dos ficheiros
    // mas com os dados retornados assincronamente por "fs.stat"
});
```

**Se quiseres usar JavaScript nativo** podes fazer assim:
(exemplo completo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/a15xupsz/)

```
var stack = [
    function(done) {
        add1mul3(4, done);
    },
    function(done) {
        add1mul3(3, done);
    }
];

function runStack(arr, done) {
    var callbacks = 0,
        total = arr.length,
        res = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        (function(index, fn) { // cria um escopo próprio
            fn(function(err, val) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                res[index] = val;
                callbacks++;
                if (callbacks == total) done(err, res);
            });
        })(i, arr[i]);
    }
}

runStack(stack, function(err, result) {
    console.log(err, result); // "null, [15, 12]"
});
```

**Usando Promises** podes usar o `Promise.all([array de promises])`. Ele recebe como argumento uma array de promises e chama o `.then` quando todas as promises tiverem resolvido, passando também uma array com os dados respetivos de cada promise, na mesma ordem.

Um exemplo seria:

```
var fns = [5, 4, 2].map(function(nr) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // correr código assincrono e depois chamar
        // resolve(com o valor final);
    });
});
Promise.all(fns).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); // [18, 15, 9]
});
```

Exemplo completo aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/w2vx7nj6/

Dei também [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137828/129) onde podes ver outro exemplo prático de `Promise.all`.

Comment: Ótima resposta, eu utilizei o `async.compose`