# Como eu posso utilizar o async/await do javascript?

Tags: javascript

Vi que agora é possível utilizar as keywords `async` e `await` no javascript, mas como isso realmente funciona?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Funções Assíncronas

Antes de mais nada precisamos falar que essas keywords fazem parte do ES2017 ([ECMAScript Latest Draft (ECMA-262)](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-function-definitions)).

Vamos por partes, primeiro sobre o `async`. Ao declarar uma **async function**, você estará, como o próprio nome já diz, declarando uma função assíncrona, que retorna um objeto [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction).

Para entender a finalidade desse recurso antes de mais nada você irá precisar entender, caso já não saiba, o que são **[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)**, um recurso já conhecido da comunidade Javascript a alguns anos. A seguir uma breve explicação:

---

#### Promises

Promise é um objeto usado para processamento assíncrono. Um Promise (de "promessa") representa um valor que pode estar disponível agora, no futuro ou nunca.

Ao receber o objeto promise, ele pode estar nos estados pendente, realizado, rejeitado ou estabelecido. Ou seja **você pode ter um objeto em mãos que em breve terá um valor, mas atualmente não tem, você tem apenas a promessa de que em algum momento esse valor será preenchido**, ou não, caso dê errado alguma coisa no percurso.

Agora que sabemos sobre os objetos promises, e que eles já funcionam de forma assíncrona, qual a finalidade das funções `async` então? Vejamos a seguir um exemplo de um promise:

```
function pegarDadosProcessados(url) {
    return baixarDados(url) // retorna uma Promise
        .catch(e => {
            return baixarDadosReservas(url) // retorna uma Promise
        })
        .then(v => {
            return processarDadosNoWorker(v); // retorna uma Promise
        });
}
```

Sendo bastante sucinto quanto a explicação, esse trecho de código basicamente é uma função que retorna um promise e dentro dele, temos processos que precisam ser executados em uma determinada ordem, logo, precisamos baixar `baixarDados(url)` e depois usando a método da promise **then** executar `processarDadosNoWorker(v)`.

Agora vejamos isso tudo utilizando funções assíncronas ou `async functions`.

---

## Utilizando Funções Assíncronas

A idéia das funções `async`/`await` é de simplificar o uso de forma síncrona dos Promises e executar alguns procedimentos em um grupo de Promises. Assim como Promises são similares a callbacks estruturados, funções async/await são similares a junção de generators com Promises.

Para essa história toda ficar mais clara vamos refazer a função anterior utilizando o async/await:

```
async function pegarDadosProcessados(url) {
    let v;
    try {
        v = await baixarDados(url); 
    } catch(e) {
        v = await baixarDadosReservas(url);
    }
    return processarDadosNoWorker(v);
}
```

Note que no exemplo acima não tem instrução `await` na instrução do **return**, porque o valor retornado de uma função async é implícitamente passado por um [Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

---

## Conclusão

Para concluír `async` é utilizado para executar funções de forma assíncrona, ou seja, funções que demandam tempo e impediriam o processo principal de continuar. Um exemplo claro dessa situação seria uma consulta ao servidor, isso pode demorar minutos dependendo da conexão com a internet da pessoa, se isso fosse feito de forma síncrona tudo iria ficar parado esperando a resposta do servidor, uma função assíncrona seria ideal para isso.

Enquanto o `await` é utilizado dentro das funções assíncronas para pausar a execução da mesma afim de esperar que uma determinada função seja executada antes de prosseguir seu processamento.

Answer (score 11):

#### O que é `async/await`?

O [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) é a terceira e mais moderna forma de trabalhar com funções assíncronas.

Esse novo tipo de funcionalidade, lançado na versão [ES2017 (ES7)](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-function-definitions), traz ao JavaScript a primeira função verdadeiramente assíncrona e é mais uma ferramenta para [trabalhar processos assíncronos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/140883/129) como as [Promises](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16921/129) e [callbacks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129).

Curiosamente a sintaxe async/await é a mais próxima de código sequencial (não assíncrono), uma vez que permite escrever o fluxo do código de maneira sequencial, e a função `async` trata de "pausar" a execução até ter uma resposta para dar.

### Como usar?

Simples, duas regras:

- usando **`async`** antes da palavra `function` na **declaração** da função que têm `await` no seu corpo/conteúdo/interior.
- usando **`await`** antes da **invocação** de uma função (nome da função) que retorna uma promise, dentro de uma `async function`.

Um aspecto a ter em conta é que `async function` retorna sempre uma Promise, e portanto usamos o `.then` para receber a resposta de uma `async function`.

### Exemplo com 2 variantes:

- Um com async/await, mais legível e sequencial
- Um com encadeamento de Promises

```js
// esta função dá "sinal verde" com x segundos de atrasado
function atrasarSegundos(delay) {
  return new Promise(
    (res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res(delay), delay * 1000)
  );
}

// este é o meu pipeline com async/await
async function meuPipeline() {
  var espera = 0;
  espera += await atrasarSegundos(1);
  espera += await atrasarSegundos(1);
  espera += await atrasarSegundos(2);
  espera += await atrasarSegundos(1);
  return 'Via await depois de ' + espera + ' segundos e 4 chamadas async';
}
meuPipeline().then(
  frase => console.log(frase)
);

// usando somente Promises 
var espera = 0; // tem de ficar fora da promise
var viaAPromise = atrasarSegundos(1).then(delay => {
  espera += delay;
  return atrasarSegundos(2);
}).then(delay => {
  espera += delay;
  return atrasarSegundos(1);
}).then(delay => {
  espera += delay;
  return atrasarSegundos(1);
}).then(delay => {
  espera += delay;
  console.log('Via await depois de ' + espera + ' segundos e 4 Promises');
});
```