# Retornar variavel de callback para a função principal com node js

Tags: node.js

Tenho uma função principal que faz a chamadas de outras funções dentro dela mesma,as 
 funções que são chamadas tem retorno com callback como mostra o código abaixo

```
async function processarFrase(frase) {
  frase = limpezaInicial(frase);
  let fraseOriginal = frase;
  if (frase.match(regexes[0])) {
    let match = await limpeza(frase);
    frase = match;
  }

  getDictionary(frase, dictionary => {
    let grupo = capturarGrupo(fraseOriginal, dictionary);
    console.log(fraseOriginal);
    console.log("Inserir isso no banco, no campo dataset: " + grupo);
    console.log("\n");
  });
}
```

o que preciso é que a função principal que é a processarFrase retorne a variavel ***grupo***  pois preciso acessar essa variavel em um outro escopo, tentei dessa forma abaixo:

```
async function processarFrase(frase) {
      let group;
      frase = limpezaInicial(frase);
      let fraseOriginal = frase;
      if (frase.match(regexes[0])) {
        let match = await limpeza(frase);
        frase = match;
      }

      getDictionary(frase, dictionary => {
        let grupo = capturarGrupo(fraseOriginal, dictionary);
        console.log(fraseOriginal);
        console.log("Inserir isso no banco, no campo dataset: " + grupo);
        console.log("\n");
        group = grupo;
      });
      return group;
    }
```

Porém sem exito, se eu fizer

```
 let grupo = processarFrase("Uma frase qualquer");
```

e der um

```
console.log(grupo)
```

o resultado é

> undefined

como faço pra que a função principal consiga retornar a variavel grupo?

Comment: Está faltando parênteses entre os parâmetros de getDictionary. Tenta dessa forma: `getDictionary((frase, dictionary), => {  } )`

Comment: Não entendi muito bem: você está tentando declarar ou chamar a função getDictionary?

Comment: Não precisa dos parenteses ,e o que preciso é que a função processarFrase , retorne aquela variável  chamada grupo . a variavel grupo é declarada dentro do callback de getDictionary , portanto criei uma variavel chamada group para armazenar o que tem em grupo

Comment: Já tentou usar `await` antes de chamar `capturarGrupo`? poste o código da função `capturarGrupo`, por favor.

Comment: Ja sim, tentei mas sem exito

Comment: o código completo no pastebin https://pastebin.com/3YmycrWC

Comment: Por que você está usando callback se a função `getDictionary` é assíncrona? já tentou o uso do `.then` ?

Comment: Não tentei, ficaria como?

Comment: Eu acredito que você está usando `async` e `await` de maneira errada, por exemplo: 
`await words.forEach(async palavra `
Particularmente, eu sempre vi o uso de ambas as palavras em requisições http/banco de dados, nunca com algo diferente. Tente retirar do seu código as palavras `async` e `await` de lugares onde não tem necessidade de usá-las. Espero que seja isso.

Comment: Aliás, não é certo usar `async` antes de uma variável (exemplo: `async palavra`). Caso queira ver mais conteúdo sobre: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211505/como-eu-posso-utilizar-o-async-await-do-javascript