# Como utilizar async/await com classes Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Criei uma classe com um método `async`, porém, quando instancio esta classe e executo o método, um erro é gerando em meu console, segue código de exemplo e erro abaixo:

**JS**

```js
class MyClass{
  async method(){
    const x = await 10; // exemplo meramente ilustrativo
    return x
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass()

const result = await instance.method()

console.log(result)
```

**Erro:**

```
const result = await instance.method()
               ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

O async/await funciona de alguma maneira diferente quando se trata de métodos de um objeto? Ou estou fazendo alguma coisa errada?

Comment: `async`/`await` funciona exatamente da mesma forma em métodos. Pelo erro parece que você está utilizando `await` fora de uma função `async`. No seu exemplo você está utilizando `await` no escopo global, o que obviamente não é possível (pode parecer possível se você fizer pelo console do seu navegador, mas isso é porque o console trata essa condição automaticamente para você, o mesmo não acontece num código que você declarou na página).

Comment: `const result = await instance.method()` não seria async?

Comment: `await`só vai ter resultado se o método onde vc esta utilizando ele for uma promesa, caso contrario náo terá efeito nenhum. Na documentacao do [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) é bem explicado isso.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Como eu posso utilizar o async/await do javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211505/como-eu-posso-utilizar-o-async-await-do-javascript)