# Como chamar um função dentro de função?

Tags: javascript, node.js, funções, api, express.js

Estou desenvolvendo uma `API`, e nela preciso implementar um método que buscar dentro da minha base de dados um filme através do seu `ID`.

Como vou utilizar esse método para realizar mais que uma unica vez, gostaria de reutiliza-lo em meu código. Para isso implementei o código a seguir que consulta o `ID` passado na requisição:

```
async function findMovie(req, res, next){
    let movie;
    try {
      movie = await Movie.findById(req.params.id);
      if (movie == null) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "Cannot find Movie" });
      }
    } catch (err) {
       return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    } 
    res.movie = movie;
    next();
}
```

Feito isso, implementei outro método que executa o  `findMovie()` quando for requisitado determinado ID através da URL:

> localhost:3000/movies/5e7688cb534f364cf269c010

```
const getMovie = (req, res) => {
    const m = m.findMovie()
    res.json(res.m)
}
```

Comment: O titulo e o corpo não está fazendo sentido ... tem como explicar melhor?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic preciso invocar a função findMovie dentro da getMovie, porém o código acima não está funcionando. Creio que a forma que estou chamando a função findMovie esteja incorreta.

Answer (score 1):

> @VirgilioNovic preciso invocar a função findMovie dentro da getMovie, porém o código acima não está funcionando. Creio que a forma que estou chamando a função findMovie esteja incorreta

Pelo comentário do usuário faltou assinar o método com `async` e no `promisse` `await` exemplo:

```
const getMovie = async(req, res) => {
    const m = await m.findMovie();
    res.json(res.m);
}
```

para aguardar o resultado de um método assíncrono. [Um boa leitura tem aqui no site a explicação de async/await](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211505/como-eu-posso-utilizar-o-async-await-do-javascript)