# Ajuda com Promisse {<Pending>}

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, promises

Fala pessoal, tudo bem? Estou fazendo uma função que será responsável por validar o CEP informado pelo usuário. Basicamente na chamada de uma API o usuário vai enviar o CEP no body e eu preciso validar se esse CEP é valido, fiz a função abaixo:

```
    const axios = require('axios')

const obj = {
    infos: {
        addres: {
            cep: '04052030',
            street: 'Rua Orissanga',
            city: 'São Paulo'
        }
    }
}

async function cepCheck (request) {
    const data = await axios.get(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${request.infos.addres.cep}/json/`)
 
    if(request.infos.addres.street != data.data.logradouro) {
        request.check = false
        return request
    }else if(request.infos.addres.city != data.data.localidade){
        request.check = false
        return request
    } else {
        request.check = true
        return request
    }

}

const teste = cepCheck(obj)
```

o Obj criado é apenas para teste. No cenário que eu descrevi eu preciso saber se o resultado do check é false ou true para retornar uma response ao usuário na API, só que ai entrar o problema, por se tratar de uma promisse o retorno sempre vem como {pending} e, eu realmente não sei como faço para contornar essa situação. Para a API eu estou utilizando o express e, caso seja necessário eu envio o código da chamada da API também.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como eu posso utilizar o async/await do javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211505/3774)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise.

<sup>Retirado do **MDM web docs** [[English]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) [[Português (do Brasil)]](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas) - em 11/08/2020</sup>

<sub>Que traduzido seria +/- isso:</sub>
O retorno de uma `async function` é sempre uma promise. Se o valor retornado dentro da `async function` não é uma promise sera transformado em uma, ou seja:

```js
async function foo() {
   return 1
}

console.log('retorno da chamada é:', foo().constructor.name)
```

é a mesma coisa que isso:

```js
function foo() {
   return Promise.resolve(1)
}

console.log('retorno da chamada é:', foo().constructor.name)
```

---

Então no seu caso `const teste` esta recebendo uma promise.
Que você poderia substituir/fazer algo como o exemplo abaixo:

```
/// teste.then(function(resultado){ ...
cepCheck(obj).then(function(resultado){
      console.log("Meu resultado é", resultado);
  })
  .catch(function(){
      console.log("Error");
  });
```

Comment: Boa, valeu Icaro, utilizei essa solução e deu certo!

Answer (score 2):

Sua função *cepCheck* é uma função assíncrona, então você precisa aguardar utilizando um await o resultado dela na variável teste (***const teste = cepCheck(obj)***)

Para testar, você pode adicionar um console.log antes do retorno na função *cepCheck* e verificar o valor desejado normalmente (já que, na função *cepCheck*, você já está usando o await) ou rodar uma função assíncrona que vai chamar internamente a função

Ex:

```
async function cepCheck (request) {
    const data = await axios.get(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${request.infos.addres.cep}/json/`)
 
    if(request.infos.addres.street != data.data.logradouro) {
        request.check = false
        return request
    }else if(request.infos.addres.city != data.data.localidade){
        request.check = false
        return request
    } else {
        request.check = true
        return request
    }

}



(async () => {
    const teste = await cepCheck(obj)
    console.log(teste)
})();
```

No meu exemplo eu encapsulei sua chamada numa função anônima assíncrona que se auto-chama logo após sua criação. Eu utilizei essa forma para conseguir criar um ambiente assíncrono sem a necessidade de criar uma outra função nomeada como o cepCheck e que pode ser implementada tranquilamente no *run* de um script.js sem sujar muito seu código