# Retornar valor em uma variavel externa de uma função exportada assincrona

Tags: javascript, node.js

Preciso pegar um valor assincrono como retorno de uma função exportada, mas atualmente estou recebendo Promise { < pending > } pois quando tento tirar a varivavel da função assincrona para poder usala ela não vem

> EXPORT carteira.js

```
require('dotenv-extended').load();
const api = require("./api");
const symbol = process.env.SYMBOL;

async function insert() {
    try {
      const account = await api.accountInfo();
      const coins = account.balances.filter(b => symbol.indexOf(b.asset) !== -1);
      let typeSymbol = coins.map((e,index)=> coins[index][Object.keys(e)[0]]);
      let valueCoin = coins.map((e,index)=> coins[index][Object.keys(e)[1]]);
      var subCoin = valueCoin[2].substr(0, 6);
      var moeda = subCoin + " " + typeSymbol[2];
      return await moeda
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error -> insert", error)
        throw error
    }
}

module.exports = {
  insert
}
```

> Import

```
require("../../public/javascripts/api");
const axios = require("axios");
const { insert } = require("../../public/javascripts/carteira");

var dinheiro =  (async function () {
  return (await insert())
})()

console.log(dinheiro);
```

Resultado esta dando como Promise { < pending > } quero retornar o valor em uma variavel para utilizar no html

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Ajuda com Promisse {<Pending>}](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/467403/ajuda-com-promisse-pending)

Comment: pior que nao ajudou , não consegui retornar o valor em uma variavel para passar pro html

Comment: Coloque um valor padrão no HTML, como "Carregando..." e, após o `await`, faça a _modificação_ do HTML. Você não pode tratar um dado recebido de modo assíncrono como síncrono.

Comment: module.exports = function (app) {

  (async function () {
    var moeda = await insert()
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.render("index", { title: moeda });
    });
  })()
}