# Quero pegar o valor de .getDownloadURL()

Tags: javascript, firebase

Eu gostaria de pegar o valor de `url_imagem` e usar como return da função `upImage`. Tentei varias coisas e não consegui achar solução.

```
function upImage(nomeDaPlanta, imgFile){

    var file = imgFile.files[0];
    console.log(file);
    storageRef.child(nomeDaPlanta + ".jpg").put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot);

        var url = snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url_imagem) {
            console.log(url_imagem);
            
        }).catch(error => {

            console.log(error);
        });

    });
    return url_imagem;
}
```

Comment: Sugiro que leia: [Como eu posso utilizar o async/await do javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211505/como-eu-posso-utilizar-o-async-await-do-javascript) e [O que são promises (promessas) em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119907/o-que-s%c3%a3o-promises-promessas-em-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua função é uma função assíncrona. Não há como retornar uma string, somente uma Promise

```
async function upImage(nomeDaPlanta, imgFile) {
  var file = imgFile.files[0];
  return storageRef
    .child(nomeDaPlanta + ".jpg")
    .put(file)
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

// logo você pode chamar a função.
upImage('planta', myFile).then((url) => {
    console.log(`minha url do arquivo enviado é ${url}`);
});

// Você também pode usar async/await (note que a função precisa ter async na frente
const url = await upImage('planta', myFile);
```