# NODEJS - variaveis globais são undefined fora de uma função arrow

Tags: mysql, node.js

No meu projeto Nodejs/Express eu tenho uma função que executa uma consulta no banco de dados MySQL, entretanto o resultado so fica dentro da função, nao consigo utilizar a variável fora da função.

```
   
    // esta função é chamada quando se acessa a rota correspondente.
    exports.consultaClientes = (req, res, next) => {
    var cadCli = [];

    credClientes((err, result) => {
      console.log("@@", result.length); // mostra 101 que é o numero de registros
      credCli = result.length;
    });
    
    console.log("&&", credCli); // mostra []
    
   };


   credClientes = (callback) => {
     mysql.getConnection((error, conn) => {
       conn.query(
         "SELECT * FROM tabClientes",
         (error, result, fields) => {
           conn.release();
           callback(null, result);
         }
       );
     });
   };
```

Alguém pode me dar uma mão? Obrigado!

Comment: Que ótimo, as pessoas que dão negativo nas nossas perguntas sem falar oq está errado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `getConnection`, tão como a função `query` do `mysql` são assíncronas.

Elas recebem um *callback* como argumento para ser executado quando elas terminarem de processar, porque essas funções não bloqueiam a execução do seu código.

No seguinte trecho do seu código:

```
credClientes((err, result) => {
  console.log("@@", result.length); // mostra 101 que é o numero de registros
  credCli = result.length;
});

console.log("&&", credCli); // mostra []
```

O que está acontecendo é

- `credClientes` é invocado
- O código não é bloqueado, e portanto `console.log("&&", credCli)` é invocado
- `credClientes` eventualmente termina de processar, e só então `credCli` recebe o novo valor

---

Se você quer trabalhar com a variável `credCli`, você precisa fazer isso dentro do *callback*, ou dentro de uma função que só irá rodar depois que o seu *callback* terminar de rodar.

Mas na verdade, todo esse paradigma está ultrapassado. Apesar de ser válido, dificilmente você verá códigos em JavaScript utilizando *callback* para tratar código assíncrono. Geralmente o que você verá na prática é o uso do `async` e `await`, o qual eu não vou explicar aqui, [mas você pode ler outras respostas do SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211505/como-eu-posso-utilizar-o-async-await-do-javascript) ou a documentação própria.

Essa seria a forma moderna em que o seu código poderia ser refatorado:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const pool = mysql.createPool(/* .. */);

async function consultaClientes(req, res, next) {
    const credCli = await credClientes();
    console.log(credCli);
}

async function credClientes() {
    const conn = await pool.getConnection();
    const [result, fields] = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM tabClientes');

    conn.release();
    return result;
}

exports.consultaClientes = consultaClientes;
```

Comment: Obrigado! Esta foi forma que encontrei de construir meu back-end, Foi através de exemplos que funcionaram, para mim. Nas pesquisas eu encontrei sim referencias ao uso do async await, e tentei usar, só que não me aprofundei. Na verdade eu desconfiei que poderia ser algo do tipo que estava acontecendo, só que não consegui implementar o async await no node, pois já uso no VUE, mas no node é diferente. Então agora vou seguir nesta linha, muito obrigado.