# Recuperar valor usando node.js e mssql

Tags: sql-server, node.js

Estou com dificuldades para recuperar um valor utilizando a biblioteca mssql

Já tentei colocar uma variável no escopo global e atualizar o valor usando o recordset, colocar tudo dentro de uma função passando o valor do recordset como retorno e usar funções de setImmediate e setTimeout, mas ainda assim ao tentar exibir no console o valor de data, é retornado "undefined"

```js
var express = require('express');
var sql = require("mssql");
var app = express();
var data;

getData();

function getData() {
    var config = {
        user: '', //usuário
        password: '', //senha
        server: '', //servidor
        database: '' //db
    };
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('SELECT ..........', function (err, array) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            data = array.recordset;
            sql.close();
        });
    });
}

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..\n' + data);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`request.query` é assíncrono. Tens de usar `data` só depois da query correr. Ou seja, **dentro** da callback.

Portanto se queres começar o servidor só depois da query ter um resultado, tens de fazer assim:

```
         // ...
        request.query('SELECT ..........', function (err, array) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            // send records as a response
            // console.log(array.recordset);
            data = array.recordset;
            sql.close();
            var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
                console.log('Server is running..\n' + data);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Dá uma olhada [nesta outra pergunta/resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/140814/129) sobre ideias para encadear código assíncrono.

Comment: E como eu conseguiria utilizar o valor retornado por "data" fora dessa função? A intenção, no final das contas, é pegar o valor resultante da query e utilizar esse modulo em outro arquivo através de module.exports

Comment: @leocabrallce o truque e diferênça na maneira de pensar em código assincrono é que tudo está encadeado. Outras partes do código não podem correr antes desta se precisam de `data`. Por isso dei o link da outra pergunta/resposta. Se tens um problema específico coloca numa pergunta que vamos ajudar.