# É possível retornar um valor dentro de um callback, sem outro callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Bem, eu tenho uma função que retorna um valor para um callback, mas eu queria que ele retornasse sem esse callback, isso é possível?

**Função em questão:**

```
function getProfile(id, fn) {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE ID in ('" + id + "')";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        fn(result[0]);
    );
}
```

**Codigo em prática:**

```
var userData = getProfile(123, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Eu queria que a variável `userData` não precisasse de callback.

Comment: No teu exemplo `var userData` não vai receber nada pois `getProfile` profile é assincrona. Tens de usar `result` de dentro da callback mesmo. Faz sentido?

Comment: Isso eu sei mas eu queria que a variável userData ficasse com o result[0] dos result da query. Isso é possível?

Comment: Fora da função não. Podes fazer isso com funções `async`, tecnologia nova que ainda está a ser implementada. Visualmente fica parecido com o que queres mas na prática a função pausa e retoma quando o valor chegar. É uma questão de gosto, [há muitas maneiras diferentes de gerir código assíncrono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/140814/129). Parece-me que tens resistência em usar callbacks porque a lógica síncrona é mais fácil de gerir. Tens de decidir que tecnologia usar e seguir em frente. Dá uma olhada a essa outra pergunta que referi.

Comment: Eu sei como funciona `async/await` mas esse não era o ponto. Porque o `con.query()` só tem callback, mas obrigado na mesma.

Comment: Isso só seria possível se a consulta ao banco de dados fosse síncrona, o que vai contra a filosofia do node, onde praticamente tudo que envolve I/O é assíncrono.

Comment: @PedroPinto dá uma olhada aqui com lógica async/await: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/g2yfa27v/ Repara que a resposta vêm passados 2 segundos

Comment: @Sergio Eu sei como funciona `async/await` .-.

Comment: @PedroPinto viste o meu jsFiddle? Ele faz exatamente o que queres, onde tens `var x = funcao();`. Não era isso que querias?

Comment: @Sergio n tinha visto obg xD