# Node js problema ao pegar valor de função

Tags: javascript, node.js, funções

Possuo a seguinte estrutura em node :

```
module.exports.find = function(pesquisa,frase){ 
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        pesquisa.find(frase, function(err,data){
            if(err)
                throw err;
            else
                resolve(data[0]['retorno']);
        });
    });
}
```

Eu gostaria de fazer a pesquisa.find retornar um valor para alguma variável onde eu pudesse manipular, ou algo do gênero.

Comment: rods, acho que esta pergunta é duplicada desta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/140814/129. Dá uma olhada lá.

Comment: Eu havia visto mas não consegui chegar a reposta correta, poderia me ajudar tomando como exemplo a minha função? 
Ficou um pouco confuso nas opções da outra pergunta

Comment: Onde queres usar `dados`? podes dar um exemplo? Sabes usar callbacks? sabes usar promises? sabes usar async/await? Desculpa bombardear com perguntas, mas é mais fácil assim para poder ajudar.

Comment: Essa função está sendo chamada de outra página, eu quero retornar os dados pra ela , ai se eu tiver com a variavel eu consigo retornar ela.
Eu tentei com promisses mas aparece pending. Ai eu tentei user o .then depois da função da promisse e cai no mesmo problema.

Comment: Coloca esse código com promise que testaste, posso explicar o que falhou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usares essa promise podes fazer assim no ficheiro que a "requere":

```
const {find} = require('./nome-do-ficheiro-da-pergunta.js');

// não sei de onde vem pesquisa, mas assumo que tu sabes
find(pesquisa, 'teste').then(data => {
    // aqui dentro podes chamar a função que precisa de "data"
    // por exemplo
    res.send(data);
}).catch(e => console.log('Erro no find...', e);
```

Comment: É isso, o segredo estava em tratar a promisse na página que a chamava, então. Obrigado, fiz as alterações necessárias e deu certo