# Diminuir código NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema em nodejs com o express. Porem estou me deparando com uma coisa que não sei ainda como resolver, preciso que um código meu retorne resultado de uma consulta do banco:

```
query = 'SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE login = ? AND senha = ?';
    array = [POST.login, POST.senha];

    // Adicione a query com scape(?) e os respectivos valores em um array simples
    connection.query(query, array, function (error, results, fields) {
        return results;
    });
```

Esta funcionando corretamente, porem só funciona dentro da rota, pois quando utilizado como uma função para economizar linhas de código, ele não retorna o valor pedido.

Também tentei utilizar a renderização dentro da função via app.use(function (req, res, next) {}); mas ele não funcionou como eu esperava e também não é oque eu preciso.

Preciso basicamente de:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    data = funcaoX();
    console.log(data);
});

router.get('/bla', function(req, res, next) {
    data = funcaoX();
    console.log(data);
});
```

E que em ambos casos data tenha o mesmo valor, vindo de uma query, para não escrever duas vezes o mesmo conteúdo.

Me desculpem qualquer coisa, estou iniciando em nodejs.

Comment: Olá Leonardo! Dá uma olhada à pergunta que indiquei em cima. Basicamente tens de criar uma função e depois exportá-la para poderes usar `require` ou `import` noutros ficheiros e invocar essa função.

Comment: Ola Sergio, talvez eu esteja me confundindo, já estou usando o require para a funcaoX(); ela esta ficando init.funcaoX();. Mas ainda não compreendi como utilizar ela com o then, ao invés de init.funcaoX(); deveria usar de que forma ?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/140814/129

Comment: Obrigado (: Consegui

Comment: Boa! Excelente!