# Problema ao mapear api com Axios e React,

Tags: react, axios

Boa tarde pessoal, tudo bem?

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação com React, no entanto, ao tentar mapear uma API aleatória, para tentar renderizar os dados, ele não consegue retornar o que estou tentando puxar.

Alguém saberia o problema ?

Ps: havia escrito "lenth" e já corrigi para "length", no entanto, não ajudou em nada. :/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

Comment: pode postar o codigo ao inves da imagem

Comment: coloque seus retornos em `console.log(retorno)` então bote para `debuggar` e veja se os dados estão sendo recebidos corretamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse método `getAll` chama uma promise e o `setState` tem de ser chamado **dentro** do `then` para ser encadeado na natureza assíncrona desse `axios.get`.

Assim o código deve ser:

```
.then(res => {
    this.setState({list: res.data});
});
```

Podes ler mais sobre encadeamentos assíncronos [aqui (link)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/140883/129).