# Como fazer uma promise encadeada com Javascript puro?

Tags: javascript, promises

Como fazer uma chamada encandeada com a promise nativa do Javascript?

Quero dizer, gostaria que a sentença abaixo fosse executada uma após a outra e que eu pudesse saber quando essa sequência de promises forem finalizadas.

```js
var promise;

console.log('iniciando...');

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(function (i) {

    promise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          resolve(i);
        }, 1000)
    });
    
    
    promise.then(function (value) {
         console.log(value);
    });
});

console.log('finalizado');
```

Comment: Você tinha que fazer uma propaganda velada pro Bolsonaro, né? Nossa, essa precisa ser gênio pra entender, eu não entenderia se não fosse eu que bolei :D

Comment: Esta pergunta não é duplicada desta outra https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/140814/129 ?

Comment: @Sergio pode martelar :p, agora que vi que são parecidas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu vi uma solução para isso no AngularJs. Adaptei essa solução para o Javascript nativo.

Veja o código abaixo:

```js
var promise = Promise.resolve();

console.log('iniciando...');

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach((i) => {

    promise = promise.then(function () {
        console.log(i);
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () { resolve(i) }, 1000)
        })
    })

});


promise.then(function (value) {
   console.log('finalizando');
});
```

Se você ver observar o código, iniciamos uma promise já resolvida e usamos o método `then`, que, por sua vez, retorna outra promise. Quando fazemos isso, o método `then` pode ser encandeado para resolver a promise retornada no `then` anterior.

Por exemplo:

```
 promiseA.then(function () {
    return promiseB;
 }).then(function () {
     return promiseC;
 })
```

Todo o segredo no `forEach` acima resume-se em igualar a variável `promise` definida externamente ao resultado da promise criada na iteração.

Quando chamamos a promise após o `forEach`, fará com que o resultado de `then` seja resolvido apenas após a promise da última iteração ser resolvida.